# Solving a differential equation 1st order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is

$$y'(t) + 2t^{-1} y(t) = x(t) $$

I keep trying an integrating factor, since it would work out nicely if I could just use $\ln(t^2)$, but it doesn't work out. Help please!

Comment: If that's $x(t)$ the solution will have an integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrating factor $\exp(\int 2dt/t ) = \exp(2\ln t)=t^2.$

Then the differential equation is
$$y'(t) t^2 +2ty(t) = x(t)\cdot t^2$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(y(t)\cdot t^2)= x(t)\cdot t^2$$

You can do the rest from here.

Answer (score 0):

The integrating factor should be $$e^{\int 2t^{-1} dt}$$